# I need to change the palette (.pal file) of multiple images at once. How can I do this?

Tags: batch, images, import

Does anyone know anyway to change the palette of multiple images at once? I have tried many different programs and there has got to be a better way than opening each image, clicking import palette and then finding the .pal file and then saving the file.
I feel like a computer could automate this but I haven't found a way to do it. I use irfanview and GIMP for batch processing images like cropping and renaming. Now I need a uniform palette to be imported and applied/saved to the image. I have thousands of images I need to change the palette and I am hitting my head against a rock. Maybe even a key record that copies my keystrokes then does it over and over again. There just has got to be a better way. Please any ideas will help!

Comment: What does this *.pal file contain? Maybe it can be done with this command line tools "ffmpeg" or "Image Magick"....

Comment: a .pal contains a palette of colors for 256 colored images. Its old school. I heard about Image Magick ill try it out thanks. Do they let you batch process multiple images?

Comment: Yes you can apply the process to multiple images at the same time. Let me see if I got it this pal allows images with 256 colores to have more colors?

Comment: no the .pal just changes the current palette to the one I need. ffmpeg looks promising, although it will take work to use it with Windows it seems. Plus I would have to change my .pal file to a .png. I may look at Image Magick next. 

A .pal file is a index of colors in a specific order. I still need the resulting image to be 256 colors but just with the new palette index that the .pal specifies.

Comment: Creating a palette in png format doesn't look difficult: "ffmpeg -i target.png -vf palettegen palette.png" where target.png is any file that is currently using the color palette from what I got. Do you neet to convert each image with the same color palette, or does every image need its own?

Comment: Yes Every image needs the same palette. That's the annoying part because they are rendered animations so each frame has a palette but not the same one. I need them to have the exact same palette, specifically the.pal file I have so that they work in a program. The program uses certain palette indexes for transparency and shadows . I would like to learn more about ffmpeg it seems promising. I can probably translate the .pal to a .png. but how to apply that to every image in folder for instance? Where I want to convert the images to have all the same palette?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you create a new palette by using one of the photos that already has the color plaette applyed to it.

ffmpeg -i SomeImage.png -vf "palettegen" MyPalette.png

Then you copy the following code to notepad and save it with the name you want but with a *.bat extension. At the "set Pal=" part you specify where you saved your color palette. Next you drag and drop the folder where the pictures are that you want to apply the color palette to are to the batch file.

For each image there should be created a new image with the same name as the old one except with "_new" in the name.

```
@echo off

:: Please inform the color palete you want to use here:
set Pal=%userprofile%\desktop\Palette.png

if exist "%~1\" (set "Folder=%~1") else (exit)

pushd "%Folder%"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.jpg *.png *.bmp') do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i "%Pal%" -lavfi "paletteuse" "%%~na_new%%~xa"
```

In this example I used a color palete with gray style colors only to make the difference more obvious:

[palette.gif](https://i.imgur.com/AfBX5P7.gif)

**Update: Using a Batch file with Irfanview:**

```
@echo off

:: Please inform the color palete you want to use here:
set Pal=%userprofile%\desktop\playpal.pal

:: Please inform the path to irfranview here:
set Irfran=C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe

if exist "%~1\" (set "Folder=%~1") else (exit)

pushd "%Folder%"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.jpg *.png *.bmp') do "%Irfran%" "%%a" /import_pal="%Pal%" /convert="%%~na_new%%~xa"
```

I tested this with a color palete that I download from here: [lospec.com](https://lospec.com/palette-list/playpal)

Comment: Well your batch program works wonderfully except it is not faithfully reproducing my palette. I specifically need green and red as my first 2 index colors but no matter what I do, the images come out with a similar palette BUT not the exact palette I need.   I used ffmpeg to make a .png, I even made a .png by hand of the exact palette with the palette information still loaded in that Palette.png as well. No matter what I do the new images get the wrong palette ! Please help if you can!                       
 https://imgur.com/AOqVQCu

Comment: Hm, maybe if you create a palette from an image it only transfers the colors it actually used and not all the colors from the original palette it was created from. I'm going to update the answer.

Comment: Although it would be nice to have a tool that automatically makes .PAL into a suitable . PNG file, my main issue is that regardless of the palette file I use, ffmpeg only wants to approximate the 256 palette index when I need an exact import of the palette index even if some colors are not present in the original image. For example In irfanview  there is a command line for but I can't get it to batch process the files or save them either. Example: /import_pal=palfile -        import and apply a special palette to the image (PAL format)

Comment: But does the irfran command has the expected result? I added another batch that uses irfanview please check answer.

Comment: Perfect answer you are truly a guru in your field!  I have been having this problem every so often for  YEARS. Irfanview community is kind of dead but the program is great, I've asked this question many times and you literally solved it in less than a day. You have saved me countless hours and eliminated the possibility I make an error on one of my images which is a nightmare to go back and search. I cannot thankyou enough. I never thought of making a batch program this is ingenious! It allows one to set the palette file and the Irfanview path while handling the images folder automatically!